# "Notebook Indexer for Windows" shows "Not Installed"

Tags: installation, configuration

Testing the latest (10.3.1) on windows to decide if it's time to move up from 9.

I note, after full install, that the *Notebook Indexer for Windows* shows as *Not Installed*.

The WindowsNotebookIndexer.dll DLL is in the appropriate folder, so something got installed it appears.

I tried re-installing the Extras, same result.

On my 9.x copy, this shows installed.

What's the deal?